# ASP.NET Custom Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, windows-authentication

Is there any way to have a custom form for Windows authentication so that the device used when authentication doesn't need to support NTLM in order to work? Also, is there a way to keep the automatic login for intranet users so that they do not need to login if they are already on their computer?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to have a custom form
>   for Windows authentication so that the
>   device used when authentication
>   doesn't need to support NTLM in order
>   to work?

I guess you want to be able to authenticate users coming from outside the intranet. 
In that case, Windows Authentication is not the right choice since it uses Windows user's credentials for the authentication and therefore more applicable for intranet applications.
If you really want to have Windows Authentication, your client requires NTLM or Kerberos authentication support.

> Also, is there a way to keep the
>   automatic login for intranet users so
>   that they do not need to login if they
>   are already on their computer?

For this you can use Windows Authentication.